# Remove scientific notation from an XML column

Tags: sql-server, cast, xquery

I have a XML column as shown below:

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <Rowid>1</Rowid>
    <date>2013-05-06</date>
    <Balance>1.0002E7</Balance>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

When I query to get the balance, I get it as `1.0002E7`. But I want to get it like this: `10002000`.

How can I do it?

Can I make any changes so that the XML column itself is stored as I want it without scientific notation?

Comment: Interestingly you have the same post on SSC but glad that you post the answer there are well .. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1456367-391-1.aspx#bm1456385

Comment: @Kin Ha. Maybe I should post my updated answer there also. Littering the internet with complicated XML queries.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson its your answer ... I thought that it should be referenced .. so you can get the credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify `float` when fetching the value from the XML.

```
select @XML.value('(//Balance)[1]', 'float');
```

To change the value in a XML column with decimals included you need to first extract the value as a `float` and write it back as an `numeric` with the appropriate precision and scale.

Something like this.

```
update T 
set XMLCol.modify('replace value of (//Balance/text())[1] 
                   with (sql:column("X.Balance"))')
from YourTable as T
  cross apply (select convert(numeric(18,4), T.XMLCol.value('(//Balance/text())[1]', 'float'))) as X(Balance)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4040/1)

The reason for the scientific notation is because it is the way SQL Server handles xs:float when using untyped XML.

From [Type Casting Rules in XQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191231.aspx)

> When casting a value of type xs:float or xs:double, or any one of
>   their subtypes, to a string or untypedAtomic type, the value is
>   represented in scientific notation. This is done only when the value's
>   absolute value is less than 1.0E-6, or greater than or equal to 1.0E6.
>   This means that 0 is serialized in scientific notation to 0.0E0.

Comment: Nice it worked.But if i want it to cast to decimal then what should i use? Also can i set the decimal with number of digits after decimal point?

Comment: @ITresearcher I have updated the answer.

Comment: SQL Fiddle, nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convert function, like so :

```
DECLARE @x XML = 
'<Root>
  <Row>
    <Rowid>1</Rowid>
    <date>2013-05-06</date>
    <Balance>1.0002E7</Balance>
  </Row>
</Root>'

SELECT CONVERT(FLOAT,(@x.value('(/Root/Row/Balance)[1]','nvarchar(100)')))
```

Comment: Ok.but can i avoid having these scientific notation in the xml itself?

Comment: That just depends on the input really, you have to have a look at the application code that's inserting the XML into the field.